# What's causing / how to get rid of long web calls in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-performance

I have a Google Sheets that's running into performance problems.  It will make really long calls and occasionally freezes up the user interface. Here's an example of the type of call that's being made consistently which takes longer than 50 seconds to respond:

[image: network]

If I inspect one of the 50 second calls, it returns barely any data:

[image: response]

I can guarantee the delay is not a network issue, as I have very consistently high network speeds:

[image: speed]

Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?

**Sheet Info**: Rows: 2,250 Columns: CC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im going to go with the assumption that what's happening here is not your connection. This is actually caused by Google servers not allocating enough resource to your requests. The reason the calls are so long is because the server is processing them so it waits for the data to return in whole before it stops. If it doesn't get enough data in x amount of time it will end transmission and create another. You could have the fastest internet in the world. But Google serves many people and can't put too much processing power in on one person. If you're not calculating very long equations that require good speed then I have no clue. But if the majority of this is solid maths then you have your answer. Google is awful if you're looking for performance in the cloud.
**Also** you *could* try offline mode. I'm assuming it will stop the call times but will stress out a low end rig if it stresses Google servers

Comment: Perhaps it's just trying to batch changes every 50 seconds so it doesn't have to make extra round trips.  Even still, it shouldn't need to do that by waiting 50 seconds to return the request, it could just re-poll every x seconds for the new data.  Also, this is a filtered list of network traffic and there's a lot of other stuff flying back and forth that keeps it almost immediately in sync with other text changes.

Comment: Isn't the vast majority of the work on a sheet being done locally?  Otherwise "work offline" wouldn't work.